# After exporting ssrs report excel name should have todays date

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I am exporting the ssrs report as an excel and i want the name of the excel to be dynamic it should also have today's date. please let me know if possible.

I am expecting that excel name should contain the report name plus the todays date.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [URL Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16) to generate the report, you can save the file with whatever name you want.